# unfortunately package installer has stopped

Tags: android, rx-java, rxpermissions

**Background:** I'm trying to make a simple with *RxPermissions* .. I created a new project with the bellow code/setup but when I launch the app I got a dialog with the message **"unfortunately package installer has stopped"**

**gradle.build**

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
  compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.7.0@aar'


  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
  // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
  // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Must be done during an initialization phase like onCreate
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        RxPermissions.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
            .request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
              @Override public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {

              }
            });
      }
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? There nothing in logcat?

Comment: I m using Android Studio 2.1.2

Comment: I don't think it's an AS version problem because I run the RxPermissions sample with the same version and do not have this problem

Comment: I just thought that you could be using an old version and that could be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to declare the permission `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` in the manifest.